# Firestore how do I check if an element exists in an array in cloud firestore using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to check if an element exists in the array in cloud firestore

here is an example element (which is an object):

```
 var viewData = {ISBN: "8388838", ItemType: "Book", Shelf_Location: "YA FIC German xxx"}
```

This is the array I am talking about.
[image: This is the array I am talking about]

Here is the code that I used to check if this element exists in an array in cloud firestore:

```
db.collection("users").doc("reservedItemsList").get().then((doc) => {
        if ((doc.data().reserved_items).includes(viewData)){
            alert("error")
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

The code above is not working because when I ran the code `console.log(typeof(doc.data().reserved_items))` it returned an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `true`/`false` answer you may use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to lookup by ISBN, which is supposed to be unique identifier:

```
if((doc.data().reserved_items).some(({ISBN}) => ISBN === viewData.ISBN)){..
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to compare the attributes in `viewData` with the objects in your `reserved_items`.

The reason you cannot use `includes()` is because the objects are not the same (even though they contain the same information.)

Consider the following example

```
const a = {foo:'asd'};
const b = {foo:'123'};
const array1 = [a, b];

console.log(array1.includes({foo:'asd'})); // false
console.log(array1.includes(a)); // true
```

You could use the `find()` function, or as mentioned in the comment, the `some()` function. Below, I used the `find()` function:

```
const foundItem = reserved_items.find(item => {
 if(item.ISBN === viewData.ISBN){
  return item;
 }
});
if(foundItem) {
// viewData exists in reserved_items
}
```

Here is how to use the [find()-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Considering OP performs the lookup within the `if(`-statement (hence expects to get boolean), it is *semantically* more appropriate to use `.some()`, which returns boolean, rather than `.find()` which returns the matching object (it will still work though).